# How can I programmatically check in a C# installer class if IIS supports Application Pools?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, installation

I am writing an installer class in which I am creating a new Application Pool. This obviously is not going to work on IIS <6.0. How can I safely check (programmatically in .Net) if IIS supports application pools before I try to add one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable relying on the version, it's in the registry

```
Key: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
Value Name: MajorVersion
```